# Find value of a Fox H-function

Tags: special-functions

I tried to evaluate the values of Fox H-function $H_{2,2}^{1,1}(t)$ at point $t>0$.
We have
$$
H_{2,2}^{1,1}\left[ t\left| \begin{array}{cc} 
(0,1) & (1,1)\newline
(1,1) & (\alpha,1) \end{array} \right. \right]
= \frac1{2\pi i} \int_L \frac{\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(1+s)}{\Gamma(1+s)\Gamma(1-\alpha - s)} t^{-s}ds.
$$
Contour $L$ must separate the poles of $\Gamma(1-s)$ and $\Gamma(1+s)$. Poles of $\Gamma(1-s)$ are natural numbers 1,2,3,..., whereas $\Gamma(1+s)$ has negative integers as poles, i.e., -1,-2,-3,.... Then we choose $L$ the imaginary axis and, after cancellation, obtain
$$
H_{2,2}^{1,1}\left[ t\left| \begin{array}{cc} 
(0,1) & (1,1)\newline
(1,1) & (\alpha,1) \end{array} \right. \right]
= \frac1{2\pi i} \int_{0-i\infty}^{0+i\infty} \frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{\Gamma(1-\alpha - s)} t^{-s}ds.
$$
Then, we need to find the residues of all poles in the left half-plane. However, function
$\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{\Gamma(1-\alpha - s)} t^{-s}$ has no poles in the left half-plane of the  complex $s$-plane.
Does this imply that Fox H-function with those parameters is equal to zero? I do not think so, but cannot figure out what I do wrong.

Comment: The integral over the vertical line diverges if $\operatorname {Re} \alpha \geq 0$. Even if it converges, the integral over a large semicircle in the left half-plane is not negligible if $t > 1$. We have to choose a contour which makes the integral convergent. A possible choice is a left loop for $t < 1$ and a right loop for $t > 1$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $\alpha>0$. However, I do not understand why integral is divergent in this case. If it diverges, does it imply that Fox H-function is infinite?